# How to Size Child of ShowDialog

Tags: dart, flutter

Using [**`showDialog(...builder: ...)`**](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart#L631), I am ***unable*** to size the content of `SomeWidget`.

#### What is happening

No matter what widgets I try to insert into the `builder` I *cannot **control** sizing*.

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  width: 10.0,
  height: 10.0,
));
```

No matter which values I insert into `width` and `height`, the dialog *always displays **full screen***. The `Container` in this case will *take up **all available space***. The code I posted above will result in the following:

[Full size screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCOOo.png) showing an Android screen, where everything except for the navigation bar, status bar and debug tag is filled out with white. *(the `SafeArea` you can see [comes from here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart#L575))*

#### Padding

Doing the same but surrounding it with a `Padding` and applying `padding` will *work as sizing*. Applying padding will remove parts from the side of the `Container`. This is the *only* successful way I have come up with. E.g. `SizedBox` or `ConstrainedBox` do not make a difference.

#### What I would like to see

Both [`CupertinoAlertDialog`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/dialog.dart#L129) and [Material `AlertDialog`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart) can be inserted as a widget to the `builder` of `showDialog` and will **not *fill up*** the whole screen.

I tried figuring out what those two widgets are doing differently than me, but to me it looks like they are [also using `Container` sizing](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/dialog.dart#L94) or [`ConstrainedBox` as sizing](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart#L80), which *both* did **not** work for me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem is: Size itself is not enough of an information to actually render it on screen.

Flutter needs a way to know how to align that 10x10 box inside the screen.
A `Center` should do the trick:

```
showDialog(
  builder: (context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(),
    )
  }
)
```

`AlertDialog` and similar do the same for you implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the **Container** Widget with **Center** Widget.

### Updated Code :

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Center(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 10.0,
      height: 10.0,
    ),
  ),
);
```